# How to choose custom quantity for each record row in Bartender?

Tags: sql, vbscript, bartender

**I have the following template set up on bartender**

```
    Product Code:           Barcode:                       Quantity:


      0001                   1234                               0
```

**Idea**

The page is set up with 1 column and 3 rows. Next, select maximum of 3 records from record picker. The 3 records chosen will then be automatically filled out onto the page.

(Records are from SQL Database)

I have a form set up with a record picker. If I choose 3 random records from the database. The output would be something like this:

```
Product Code:           Barcode:                       Quantity:

    0001                   1234                            0

    0002                   1235                            0

    0003                   1236                            0
```

**My Question is**

when pressed `Print`. How can I adjust the quantity for each record?

**Images:**

Data Entry Form
[image: Data Entry Form]

Data for each row
[image: Data for each row]

Page template
[image: Page template]

Comment: Just to be clear... Quantity is not a database column in this case? And, you want to edit that manually, for each label, one record at a time? Finally, what is your version of bartender?

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for your problem. The first and my preferred is to add a column for quantity. Simply right click on the record picker and choose properties. go to the tab Record Picker and search for the option "Selector Column". If you change this to Quantity, you will be able to add a unique quantity for each record and you can remove the number input box. 
[image]

The second solution is to use the number input box. Simply linking it to the copies field should do the trick but you will need to run the form multiple times to print every record since it will close after every print. To link the field just look to the left side of the screen when your in the form builder and drag "copies" on the number input box. To solve the issue of the form you can use an option "repeat data entry until cancelled. This will reopen the print form until you close it. you can select this option in the print screen (ctrl+p) and select Options in the lower half of the screen. Select the option "repeat data entry until cancelled" and you're set.

[image]

[image]